In Adam Roberts' "Yellow Blue Tibia" why do the patrons of the Pushkin Club become hostile?
Skvorecky is taken to talk to UFO enthusiasts at the Pushkin Club. They seem to take all his denials as confirmations. After his 'talk':

Applause filled the little space ... Feeling oddly powerless in the face of this public approbation ...

So it seems that the 'talk' was well received.
But as he leaves:

And we picked our way through the tables of the Pushkin, crammed with faces now scowling and hostile, where before they had been eager and welcoming ...

What am I missing?
